# Best Practice for resilience of messages across RabbitMQ queues

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to understand the best use of RabbitMQ to satisfy the following problem.

As context I'm not concerned with performance in this use case (my peak TPS for this flow is 2 TPS) but I am concerned about resilience.

I have RabbitMQ installed in a cluster and ignoring dead letter queues the basic flow is I have a service receive a request, creates a persistent message which it queues, in a transaction, to a durable queue (at this point I'm happy the request is secured to disk). I then have another process listening for a message, which it reads (not using auto ack), does a bunch of stuff, writes a new message to a different exchange queue in a transaction (again now happy this message is secured to disk). Assuming the transaction completes successfully it manually acks the message back to the original consumer.

At this point my only failure scenario is is I have a failure between the commit of the transaction to write to my second queue and the return of the ack. This will lead to a message being potentially processed twice. Is there anything else I can do to plug this gap or do I have to figure out a way of handling duplicate messages.

As a final bit of context the services are written in java so using the java client libs.

Paul Fitz.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: You are sending message *m* from *A* to *B* and then **without** *B* ACKing, you are "forwarding" *m* to *C*, and once *C* has finished processing, you want that it somehow ACKs to *B* which will only then ACK to *A*. Is that the case?

Comment: I have process 1 write to queue A (this I do in a transaction so I am confident with the relaibility of this action).
I have process 2 that needs to read from queue A, do some stuff and write to queue B.
My requirement is not to lose the message if anything goes wrong up to and including securing the message on to queue B.
At the moment I'm writing the message on to queue B in a txn and then doing a manual ack back to queue A.
The problem I see is that there is no overlap between that txn completeing and the ack going back to queue A so potentially I can have duplicate messages.

Comment: To your particular use case, redelivered message will be tagged as redelivered. So if your transaction is successful, you can omit the message. But to know that the transaction has been successful, you must implement some messages repository... which can fails too. If you can implement idempotency and take care of failure points and recovery and monitoring.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I suggest you to look a this guide [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) which has a lot of valid information on your topic.

From the RabbitMQ guide:

**At the Producer**

> When using confirms, producers recovering from a channel or connection
>   failure should retransmit any messages for which an acknowledgement
>   has not been received from the broker. There is a possibility of
>   message duplication here, because the broker might have sent a
>   confirmation that never reached the producer (due to network failures,
>   etc). **Therefore consumer applications will need to perform
>   deduplication or handle incoming messages in an idempotent manner.**

**At the Consumer**

> In the event of network failure (or a node crashing), messages can be
>   duplicated, and consumers must be prepared to handle them. **If
>   possible, the simplest way to handle this is to ensure that your
>   consumers handle messages in an idempotent way rather than explicitly
>   deal with deduplication**.

So, the point is that is not possibile in any way at all to guarantee that this "failure" scenario of yours will not happen. You will always have to deal with network failure, disk failure, *put something here* failure etc.

What you have to do here is to lean on the messaging architecture and implement if possibile "**idempotency**" of your messages (which means that even if you process the message twice is not going to happen anything wrong, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194081/idempotency-barrier-for-messaging)).
If you can't than you should provide some kind of "**processed message**" list (for example you can use a guid inside every message) and check this list every time you receive a message; you can simply discard them in this case.

To be more "theorical", [this](http://bravenewgeek.com/you-cannot-have-exactly-once-delivery/) post from Brave New Geek is very interesting:

> Within the context of a distributed system, you cannot have
>   exactly-once message delivery.

Hope it helps :)